# Error in building custom kernel on ubuntu 18.04 with kernel version 5.4.0-66

Tags: kernel, compiling, dkms

I am building/compiling the custom kernel 5.4.0-66 version source code.

I followed the process mentioned in the link as provided by Ubuntu: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

The below commands are used to compile the linux kernel source code
`

## LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules clean

## LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs

## LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch

`

After some time I get the kernel compilation error.

`dpkg-deb: error: 'zfs-dkms_0.8.3-1ubuntu12.6_all.deb' is not a Debian format archive`

When checked the size of file `zfs-dkms_0.8.3-1ubuntu12.6_all.deb`, it was found to be size zero.

This is strange, I used the same source code earlier and never got this error while compiling.

When I debugged further, I found that the below curl statement is able to download the zero size debian package.

`curl --fail --show-error https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/zfs-dkms_0.8.3-1ubuntu12.6_all.deb -o zfs-dkms_0.8.3-1ubuntu12.6_all.deb -D zfs-dkms_0.8.3-1ubuntu12.6_all.deb.hdr`

The error here is that, during custom kernel compilation the size of the downloaded package zfs-dkms_0.8.3-1ubuntu12.6_all.deb is shown as zero.
Kinldy suggest, why the kernel is not getting compiled even after following the process mentioned in the above link and following the commands.

Thanks and Regards,
/A\nurag

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks waltinator for you comments. I used the basic kernel compilation steps as provided by ubuntu in the link above. 2ndly the link is used by dkms-build script which is again a part of the ubuntu kernel build scripts. There are no typos or missed lines.